# How to store the data in the following structure?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist, hashmap

```
try {
    regions = json.getJSONArray(TAG_REGIONS);
    for (int i = 0; i < regions.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = regions.getJSONObject(i);
        String regionName = c.getString(TAG_REGION_NAME);
        areas = json.getJSONArray(TAG_AREA);
        for (int j = 0; j < areas.length(); j++) {
            JSONObject d = areas.getJSONObject(j);
            String areaName = d.getString(TAG_AREA_NAME);
            shops = json.getJSONArray(TAG_SHOP);
            for (int k = 0; k < shops.length(); k++) {
                JSONObject e = shops.getJSONObject(k);
                String id = e.getString(TAG_ID);
                String shopName = e.getString(TAG_SHOP_NAME);
                String shopNameForGoogle = e.getString(TAG_SHOP_NAME_GOOGLE);
                String img = e.getString(TAG_IMAGE);
                String address = e.getString(TAG_ADDRESS);
                String tel = e.getString(TAG_TEL);
                String hrs = e.getString(TAG_HRS);
                String lat = e.getString(TAG_LAT);
                String lng = e.getString(TAG_LNG);
            }
        }
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The above is the data collected from json file. The structure is

```
regions
->areas
->shops
```

Should I use arrayList to store it? How to reference after I store a list of shops ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On a high level, something like a [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) fits.

In the code, some basic approaches are as follows:

### Approach 1:

```
Region
 List<area>
    List<shops>
```

This will make your retrievals/insertions and deletions a real pain. But on the plus side its simple enough to understand and iterate.

### Approach 2:

2 maps: `Region -> List<area>` and `Area -> List<shops>`

Performs better than 1st.

### Approach 3:

Single map: `Region+Area -> List<shops>`. Can have too many keys depending on the region and area count.